# How to delete items from a list if an item in another list is equal to 0?

Tags: python

I have 3 lists, radius, x, and y. Each one is the same length. I want to delete the 'i'th item from each list if the 'i'th item in radius is equal to 0. Below is the code I am trying to use, but for some reason is not working. Thank you in advance!

```
for i in range(len(radius)):
    if radius[i]==0:
        radius.remove(i)
        x.remove(i)
        y.remove(i)
```

Comment: In the argument of remove, you give the actual item, not item index. Use del

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

Breaking this down will give you a good understanding of python variable unpacking, list comprehensions, and how `zip` works.

```
x,y, radius = zip(*[(i,j,r) for i,j,r in zip(x,y,radius) if r != 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `list.index` to get the index of the `0` element in `radius` and then just delete it from `radius`, `x` and `y`:

```
radius = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2]
x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

index = radius.index(0)
```

Now that you have the `index`, delete:

```
del radius[index], x[index], y[index]
```

If many zeros exist, you could incorporate this in a loop with a `try-catch` to break if `index` cannot find another `0`.

Comment: This should work, too, but it has quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good case for a list comprehension:

```
In [1]: x, y, r = [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,0,1,0]

In [2]: x, y, r = zip(*[xyr_i for xyr_i in zip(x,y,r) if xyr_i[2] != 0])

In [3]: print(x)
(1, 3)

In [4]: print(y)
(1, 3)

In [5]: print(r)
(1, 1)
```